# File Watch Application fails when file saved by remote user

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

My problem is this, and before I annoy anybody, this is my first post so if I err, forgive me.

I have created a simple windows service with a file system watcher that triggers a console application if a .txt file is pasted. The service is running as Local System, and works perfectly. However, the files it watches for are saved every morning by a remote user, and the console application fails without cause. If I save the file, the service AND the console application do exactly what they are supposed to.

The console application uses the GeneticParsing Library to read the file into a table, bulk loads it into an oracle 11g db on a remote server, then archives the file. The main code for the console application is below... any help would be much appreciated!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(args[0].ToString());

            Thread.Sleep(15000);

            GenericParserAdapter p = new GenericParserAdapter();
            p.ColumnDelimiter = '|';
            p.SetDataSource(f.FullName);
            DataTable d = new DataTable();
            d = p.GetDataTable();
            bb_usage_methods b = new bb_usage_methods(false);
            DataTable d_merge = new DataTable();
            d_merge.Columns.Add("BB_USAGE_ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
            d_merge.Columns.Add("USAGE_DATE", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
            d_merge.Columns.Add("PARTY_CODE", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
            d_merge.Columns.Add("UPLOAD_USAGE", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
            d_merge.Columns.Add("DOWNLOAD_USAGE", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
            d_merge.Columns.Add("TOTAL_USAGE", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));

            DataRow r;
            object j = b.get_data_from_datareader("SELECT MAX(BB_USAGE_ID) FROM USAGE");
            Int32 max_id = j.ToString() == "Entry is NULL" || j.GetType() == System.Type.GetType("System.Exception") ? max_id = 1 : max_id = Convert.ToInt32(j) + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < d.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                r = d.Rows[i];
                try
                {
                    object[] o = { max_id, Convert.ToDateTime(r[0]), Convert.ToDecimal(r[1]), Convert.ToDecimal(r[2]), Convert.ToDecimal(r[3]), Convert.ToDecimal(r[4]) };
                    d_merge.Rows.Add(o);
                    max_id++;
                }
                catch { }
                r = null;
            }
            decimal original_count = Math.Round((decimal)(d.Rows.Count * 100) / d_merge.Rows.Count, 2);
            b.bulk_insert_into_oracle(d_merge, "USAGE");                
            DateTime dt = f.LastWriteTime;

            try
            {
                File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.Replace(f.Name, @"\..\Archive\" + f.Name));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               // code to log error to db
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // code to log error to db
        }
    }
}

public class log_methods : x.oracle_data_access
{
    public log_methods()
    {
       base.get_dataset("SELECT * FROM APP_LOG", "LOG_ID");
    }
}

public class bb_usage_methods : x.oracle_data_access
{
    public bb_usage_methods(Boolean get_dataset)
    {
        if (get_dataset)
        {
            base.get_dataset("SELECT * FROM USAGE", "BB_USAGE_ID");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the filewatcher sees that file?
Is the program launched at all when remote user saves it.

If i remember right, there are some case where the filewatcher doesn't trigger when it should (in remote or whatnot).

Comment: Yeah, I omitted a bunch of code from above that logs the procedure at various points. The system logs before the parser before it stops. The problem is that I have no way to find out if it's the parser that drops or that the program keeps running further down but logging fails to commit to the DB.